# How to set "cursor" to "pointer" on Vuetify <v-data-table> rows?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to set `cursor: pointer` on Vuetify `<v-data-table>` rows ?

I tried the code below in my component, but it's not recognized:

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally fixed it this way:

```
</template>
<v-data-table class="row-pointer"></v-data-table>
<template>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.row-pointer >>> tbody tr :hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can override the rows of v-data-table component with a custom css selector. The accepted answer only works in scoped stlyes.

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table class="row-pointer" ...></v-data-table>
</template>

<style> 
.row-pointer > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:hover {  
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27275409).

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately, this did not work for me, I had to write the whole item-template

```
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <tr class="row-pointer" @click="handleRowClick(item)">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.email}}</td>

        <td>
          <v-simple-checkbox v-model="item.active" disabled></v-simple-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>

scss:
.row-pointer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The solution provided by @devondahon works perfectly with css scoped as he suggested, not with scss which maybe is what you're doing.

Comment: You can just add ::v-deep at the beginning of the selector in scss to make it work

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this:

```
<v-data-table style="cursor: pointer" @click="handleClick">
```

Should work on other components like v-row too

```
<v-row style="cursor: pointer" @click="handleClick">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-data-table
:style="\`cursor: pointer\`"
>
```

Comment: This solution turns the cursor to a pointer on each part(read whole) of the table, not just rows.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions is:

**Template**

```
 <v-data-table
  class="row-pointer"
 />
```

**Style**

```
::v-deep .row-pointer {
  tbody {
    tr {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```